# how to wrap variable by single quote instead of double quotes in php

Tags: php

**Code:**

```
<input type="text" class="hide" id="z-scharge" value='<?php echo $zero_service_charge; ?>' />
```

this produces the following output:

```
<input type="text" class="hide text" id="z-scharge" value="5" style="display: none;">
```

My expected output is:

```
<input type="text" class="hide text" id="z-scharge" value='5' style="display: none;">
```

Is it possible by any trick?

Comment: y do u want to use single-quotes?

Comment: yes. I want to wrap the value by single-quotes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That code will output the attribute `value` with single quotes.

However, the HTML is parsed by the browser and turned into a document object, which is displayed to the user. In that browser, you can inspect elements, but when you do, you don't get the exact information as it is in the source. The browser can make small alterations based on how it parses it. For instance, it may show all attribute values as double quoted values.

To make sure, choose 'View source' and view the exact and complete source of the response.